# Why is this an NFA, but not an FA?

Tags: automata

[image]

It doesn't have non-deterministic paths.

Every transition is one-to-one.

Accepted states are defined/guaranteed on specific inputs.

Not sure why its not an FA

**Edit:** 0.0.2

[image]

Comment: There are no transitions from the accepting state.

Comment: @saul I think the convention is that any missing transitions are taken as going to a "black hole" state, a non-accepting state that can't be left.

Comment: It might help if we could see 0.0.2

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I added 0.0.2, still don't understand why its not a FA.

Answer (score 1):

Nvm, figured it out.

The transition function $\delta$ must be total in a FA.

In the 1st example, at the accepting state $q_1$, $\delta(q_1, 0)=undefined$.

Whereas in the 2nd example, if we label the states $q_0, q_1,q_2$ from left to right, at the accepting state $q_1$, $\delta(q_1, 0)=q_2$.

Comment: OK. Not every author uses that convention. As I wrote in the comments, some authors use the convention that missing transitions go to a state like the one you call $q_2$ and I call a "black hole".

Comment: I'm going off on a tangent, and it's a pretty trivial thing anyway, but it's never correct to write "$= undefined$", because "undefined" isn't an expression or a variable, it's an adjective. It's a bit like writing "$6 = even$".